# Can't convert curve to mesh

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I have a problem converting curve to mesh just in the file I'm working with now. If I open a new file in Blender all is working perfectly.

Curve to Mesh, Mesh to Curve there are no problems.
It is something wrong with the settings in the actual file, but I have no idea what it could be.

I can create a Curve from Menu, I can convert a Curve from Mesh.

[image]

But once converted, it disappears in Viewport I can't manipulate it in there. I can't select, edit, or delete it in viewport. I can select or delete it just in ViewLayer.

[image]

I can change bevel of Curve in Geometry section. Then I change it, the curve appears in viewport, but there are no vertices or edges.

[image]

And then I try to convert the curve to mesh, it doesn't work.

[image]

In the Menu looks as if it has converted, but in ViewLayer remains the same curve icon.

[image]

Any idea where to start looking?

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question; I can't easily explain why you are unable to convert curve to mesh in this particular project. However, you may want to try the following as a work-around: 1) Add all your current objects and collections into a 'Root' collection, and save your project. 2) Start a fresh project. 3) Use File > Append and browse to your original project (with the 'Root' collection). Open Collections > Root. This will import all of the objects from your original project into a fresh project (with default settings).

Comment: I did it, and it works. Thank You very much for your idea. Although it's not the most elegant way to solve the problem, the most importante is that it work. Sometimes the Reset o Switch off is the best solution! :)

Comment: It would be great of you (or @SlickRed ?) if you could write a short answer to this and mark it as **Accepted Answer** so that this question shows up as solved. Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't sure I should post this as an answer given that it does not DIRECTLY solve the problem, but I'll go ahead and do so.

Comment: @SlickRed If it solves the question, then the answer is valid, ...from my point of view ;-)

Comment: Absolutely right. The Answer is Accepted. The question is solved. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question; I can't easily explain why you are unable to convert curve to mesh in this particular project.

However, you may want to try the following as a work-around:

- Add all your current objects and collections into a 'Root' collection, and save your project.
- Start a fresh project.
- Use File > Append and browse to your original project (with the 'Root' collection). Open Collections > Root.

This will import all of the objects from your original project into a fresh project (with default settings).